# Update the value in list view of second form recieved from first form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have 2 forms. The first form has textboxes for taking inputs from users and then there is 2nd form which has a list view and values taken in form1 are getting displayed in the listview of form2.

Now I want to update the record of listview, so I made a function in form2 and sent a string from form1 so it gets updated in listview of form2.

```
     form1 code
      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           showdata show= new showdata();
            string n = textBox1.Text;
            show.frstName1(n);
        }
```

This is the function in form2 where I want to update the text in the listview of form2 recvd from form1.

```
  public void frstName1 (string frstName)
        {
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = frstName;
        }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: If you call form2's methods from form1, you can't create a new form2 every time you update it. You should make form2 public (note the closing of the form2 pair). Is your listview1 currently empty? Should you try methods like add?

Comment: Yes, I am not creating a new forms again nd again. i just added it inside function to make it clear what actually the object show is. Yes I have added the method of add its working fine, but when i try to update the values that are already in list, then the values arent getting update.

Comment: @Chetan the values in list view are not getting update, giving this error. InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: `showdata show= new showdata();` this create a new object of showdata on every button click. Since the new object of  showdata does not have any item in the list and you are trying to access `listView1.SelectedItems[0]` you are getting this error.

Comment: You should create `showdata show= new showdata();`  at the form level and just call method `show.firstName1(n)` in button click.

Comment: I already said i have added data in list view and its visible in list view, but when i try to update the value then it give error.